# Update the query to combat google bot hacking

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a code in php where i m clikcing on women products or any other link for any other product.On click of which i m going to next page and passing the product name in querystring.
And then in next page i m using my sql query,which will give me the list of products which u clicked on first page.There are lot of queries in my project like this one.This query is quite prone to Google bots hacking with SQL injection.Following is the code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list">
            <li><h3><a href="search.php?name=women-top">tops</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="#">suits</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="#">jeans</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="search.php?name=women">more</a></h3></li>
            </ul>
</body>
</html
```

Search.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'shop');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$lcSearchVal=$_GET['name'];
//echo "hi";
$lcSearcharr=explode("-",$lcSearchVal);
$result=count($lcSearchVal);
//echo $result;



$parts = array();
$parts1=array();
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
    $parts[] = '`PNAME` LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($lcSearchWord).'%"';
    $parts1[] = '`TAGS` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
    //$parts[] = '`CATEGORY` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM xml where'.'PNAME LIKE ?');
var_dump($stmt);
$parts='%women%';
$stmt->bind_param('s',$parts);

$list=array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $list[]=$row;
  }
}


    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();
foreach($list as $array)
{
?>
            <div class="image">
<img src="<?php echo $array['IMAGEURL']?>" width="200px" height="200px"/></a>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The query i m using above is quite prone to Google Bot hacking.Please guide me what should i change in this query so that Google Bot wont be able to hack my application with mysql injection..There are some other similar queries in my application to this one.Please guys help me on this.

Comment: First you should stop using `mysql_`. It's deprecated which means no more support and not available in latest version of PHP. Second, you should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` with **prepared statements**. They help against SQL Injection.'

Comment: k.in place of mysql,i shud use mysqli,ryt?and i shud also use prepared statements for this....

Comment: Yes, check out this nice [tutorial](http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) for `mysqli_*` with prepared statements.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger-I will update my snippet in some minutes sir with ur article.please check whether its secure one from Google bot attack...

Comment: StackOverflow is for solving problems, not reviewing code. There is a site exclusively for this purpose - **[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**. I suggest you make the upgrade your mysql code, and post a new question on that site. They would tell you if your code is safe enough.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is open to SQL injection is that you have not escaped the input.

For example you have the line:-

```
$parts[] = '`PNAME` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
```

If someone had used a link something like as follows (ignoring the encoding to get it to work in a URL):-

```
search.php?name=fred%' UNION SELECT * FROM users #
```

the SQL you would land up with would be something like:-

```
SELECT * FROM xml WHERE  (`PNAME` LIKE "%fred%' UNION SELECT * FROM users #%")limit '.$offset.', '.$limit1.'
```

then they can execute a query to get data from the other table (possibly one containing the passwords, etc), with just a bit of patience getting the right number of columns, etc.

If you switch to mysqli_* you can use parameterised queries, but these are a minor pain when the SQL itself changes (as yours does in this case with a variable number of LIKE statements).

The simple solution would be to use mysql_real_escape_string() / mysqli_real_escape_string() on the variable you use in the SQL.

```
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord )
{
    $parts[] = '`PNAME` LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($lcSearchWord).'%"';
    $parts1[] = '`TAGS` LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($lcSearchWord).'%"';
    //$parts[] = '`CATEGORY` LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($lcSearchWord).'%"';
}
```

It is worth switching to mysqli_* if you can.

EDIT

Played with script using mysqli_() and a class and function to cope with variable numbers of parameters

```
<?php
session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'shop');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if (array_key_exists('name', $_GET))
{
    $lcSearchVal = $_GET['name'];

    $lcSearcharr = explode("-",$lcSearchVal);
    $result = count($lcSearchVal);

    $parts = array();
    foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
        $parts[] = "%$lcSearchWord%";
    }

    $bindParam = new BindParam(); 

    $parms = array();
    foreach($parts as $aPart)
    {
        $parms[] = ' PNAME LIKE ? '; 
        $bindParam->add('s', $aPart); 
    }

    $query = 'SELECT IMAGEURL FROM xml where '.implode(' OR ', $parms); 

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt)
    {

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), refValues($bindParam->get())); 

        if ($stmt->execute()) 
        {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
            {
                echo '<div class="image"><img src="'.$row['IMAGEURL'].'" width="200px" height="200px"/></a>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo $mysqli->error;
        }

        $stmt->close();

        $mysqli->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }
}
else
{
?>
<ul id="list">
    <li><h3><a href="search.php?name=women-top">tops</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="#">suits</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="#">jeans</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="search.php?name=women">more</a></h3></li>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

function refValues($arr)
{ 
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+ 
    { 
        $refs = array(); 
        foreach($arr as $key => $value) $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
        return $refs; 
    } 
    return $arr; 
} 

class BindParam
{ 

    private $values = array(), $types = ''; 

    public function add( $type, $value )
    { 
        $this->values[] = $value; 
        $this->types .= $type; 
    } 

    public function get()
    { 
        return array_merge(array($this->types), $this->values); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please see my updated code once.whether its a secure sql command or still something wrong there

Comment: Looks like it is, although that will depend on whether $limit, $limit1 and $offset are taken from user input.

Comment: even after removing these variables also it didnt work

Comment: Do you mean the script doesn't work (there are issues with your script - eg you loop around the contents of $nameArray2 at the bottom but have no closing braces for the loop - also you have session_start() after you have output part of the page), or do you mean that people can still attack the page with sql injection?

Comment: i edited my post,but still there is some error in prepare statement.i m not able to spot the error.please correct the error sir..

Comment: This is where prepared statements get to be a problem. You have an array called $parts that contains statements. But you then have a single ? for a single parameter value (not an array or values, nor statements). I will have a play.

Comment: @Kickstart-what to do here sir.

Comment: Added a version of your script that uses mysqli_ and copes with a variable number of parameters. Code for the variable number of parameters nabbed from the php manual pages - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php